# GoDaddy server closing connection when client sends multiple POST requests in a short interval of time

Tags: php, mysql, angular, ionic-framework, godaddy-api

I’m using Ionic Framework (Angular v9) to send POST requests to the PHP files hosted on the GoDaddy server. POST requests work fine until the client sends them intermittently. However, when the client starts to send multiple POST requests to the server the requests are being rejected. The server responds with one of the following errors:

1. err connection closed
2. err connection timed out
3. err_connection_reset

Scenario where such errors are spotted - Autocomplete implementation. I’ve a product Table (phpmyadmin - MySQL DB) and a PHP file to retrieve data from that table. There is a textbox on the client side app. The user begins entering the name of the product. The app fetches the values from the textbox and sends a POST request to the server. The server extracts the value from POST request and queries the table for values that match the input string. Top 5 such results are sent back to the client.

This flow works as long as the client fires the POST requests slowly, i.e. enough time interval (a few seconds) elapses between 2 requests. However, this ideal scenario is impractical. User’s typing speed wouldn’t allow the passage of such interval. I want to query the DB and have the server return results on each keydown event.

But the problem is that the server is closing the connection / resetting the connection when the same client sends too many POST requests to the server without leaving enough time interval between any 2 requests.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Could simply be a restriction GoDaddy applies, I’d ask them first of all.

Comment: If the server is setup to close or reject connections that happen on a too short interval, than it is difficult to fix this (especially on hosted server where you have limited or no server settings available). The best solution is to lower the user experience and implement a sleep timer to limit the amount of requests made per second (yes you are making multiple per second if you query the database on every keydown event).

Comment: i agree with @Fullslack.dev , maybe just slowing down a little bit the post from the client would be a good intermediate solution if you have no settings control of the server. So i  would reccomend to commit the result with a button instead autocomplete or redefine the autocomplete in a way you can send data after a sleep from no keyboard typed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can you need to learn actual limitation (allowed POST request rate from your client to the server), then work off that.

But generally speaking you need to employ a debounce technique. Even if your host provider would allow that many requests it is not a great idea to have that volume coming out of a single client.

1. You can use in-built debounce for components such a [ion-searchbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar)
2. You can use [debounceTime](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime) RXJS operator to pipe your POST requests (so that it won't fire more often than it should)
3. You can assess caching of such auto-complete details on client to prevent frequent requests

Example with ion-search:

```
<ion-searchbar debounce="500"></ion-searchbar>
```

Example with debounceTime and formControl:

```
  constructor() {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.searchControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(700))
      .subscribe(search => {
        
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers recommended that I should contact GoDaddy before diving headlong into this issue. So after contacting GoDaddy I found out that SHARED servers are not very good for data intensive applications. If the client makes too many requests to the server in a short interval of time it is in our best interest to upgrade to a PRIVATE VPS server. Simply beefing up a shared server won't necessarily improve the performance of the app or lift up any restrictions imposed.

Another suggestion I received from a senior developer was to optimise the DB. Normalisation, indexing, applying appropriate constraints and relations among tables etc. should be performed. If the DB is not optimised certain servers might close the connection and the POST requests could fail.